# Anyone know what does mb stand for in the mbunit?

Tags: mbunit, gallio

Just a little bit curious, what does "MB" mean in "MBUnit"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means *Much Better* Unit Testing Framework :)

More seriously, it means **Model Based** Unit Testing Framework (ref. ["Crafting A Toolchain", Jeff Brown, SFCon 2009](http://www.slideshare.net/ConSanFrancisco123/gallio-crafting-a-toolchain))